# How to save List of Dictionaries in a .txt or .doc file in prettify format?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries in python.

```
[{'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 34731019, 'yId': 28782454, 'zId': 'dafd'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 48046171, 'yId': 28984154, 'zId': 'mmgj'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 32363003, 'yId': 29164259, 'zId': 'adfa'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 47434038, 'yId': 29164447, 'zId': 'uyti'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 50867569, 'yId': 29165098, 'zId': 'qeqq'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 14321214, 'yId': 29271302, 'zId': 'gddf'}}]
```

I am able to print it in prettify way.
But don't know how to write it in a .txt file in prettify format.

I am able to print it on Terminal in prettify format like this by using `pprint` module.

```
pprint.pprint(listOfDict, sort_dicts=False)
```

output:

```
[{'type': 'myPersonalInfo',
  'isPublic': False,
  'model': {'xId': 34731019, 'yId': 28782454, 'zId': 'dafd'}},
 {'type': 'myPersonalInfo',
  'isPublic': False,
  'model': {'xId': 48046171, 'yId': 28984154, 'zId': 'mmgj'}},
 {'type': 'myPersonalInfo',
  'isPublic': False,
  'model': {'xId': 32363003, 'yId': 29164259, 'zId': 'adfa'}},
 {'type': 'myPersonalInfo',
  'isPublic': False,
  'model': {'xId': 47434038, 'yId': 29164447, 'zId': 'uyti'}},
 {'type': 'myPersonalInfo',
  'isPublic': False,
  'model': {'xId': 50867569, 'yId': 29165098, 'zId': 'qeqq'}},
 {'type': 'myPersonalInfo',
  'isPublic': False,
  'model': {'xId': 14321214, 'yId': 29271302, 'zId': 'gddf'}}]
```

But how can I write this in a .txt or .doc file in prettified format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `pprint.pprint` use `pprint.pformat`, then save normally:

```py
import pprint

d = [{'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 34731019, 'yId': 28782454, 'zId': 'dafd'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 48046171, 'yId': 28984154, 'zId': 'mmgj'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 32363003, 'yId': 29164259, 'zId': 'adfa'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 47434038, 'yId': 29164447, 'zId': 'uyti'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 50867569, 'yId': 29165098, 'zId': 'qeqq'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 14321214, 'yId': 29271302, 'zId': 'gddf'}}]


with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(pprint.pformat(d))
```

This however won't let you read the file as json, so you might settle on another readble format using `json.dump` with `indent=4`:

```py
import json

d = [{'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 34731019, 'yId': 28782454, 'zId': 'dafd'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 48046171, 'yId': 28984154, 'zId': 'mmgj'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 32363003, 'yId': 29164259, 'zId': 'adfa'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 47434038, 'yId': 29164447, 'zId': 'uyti'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 50867569, 'yId': 29165098, 'zId': 'qeqq'}}, {'type': 'myPersonalInfo', 'isPublic': False, 'model': {'xId': 14321214, 'yId': 29271302, 'zId': 'gddf'}}]

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: `pprint` takes a `stream` argument, so you can also do: `pprint.pprint(d, stream=f)`.

Comment: @craigb Since neither will make the file json-readble, it might be better to dump `pprint` and use `json.dump` with `indent=4` anyway

Comment: yes, agreed that would be better.  I was just trying to directly answer the question of putting `pprint` output into a file.